# Laravel updateOrCreate with auto-incremental database

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

My purpose is to **update if the value exists, else inserts a new row** in the database table after submitting the form.

The problem is, the function here **adds new columns** in db table **instead of updating them.**

Here's my function :

```
MyModel::updateOrCreate(array(
    'myField' => 'myValue',
))
    ->where('myAutoIncrementalField', '=', '5')
    ->where('myPrimaryKey', '=', '8');
```

My database table is like that :
1. myPrimaryKey (not auto incremental and is fillable on model.)
2. myAutoIncrementalField (auto incremental and cannot be fillable on model.)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is how you use this method:

```
Model::updateOrCreate(
   ['primary_key' => 8],
   ['field' => 'value', 'another_field' => 'another value']
);
```

As 1st param pass an array of fields that are unique, or in your case, the primary key. Non-unique fields don't make sense here obviously just like passing anything along with the PK.

2nd param is an array of values that should be updated/created too, but being ignored in the unique/pk search.

Comment: It works. This is exactly what i wanted. I couldn't find any documentation in Laravel API or documents, if you share the way how to analyze this kind of problems i would be appreciated. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Well, I know Eloquent ins and outs. But if I did not, I would probably open `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php` file and check the source. Laravel source has pretty much everything in the comments. The codebase is updated much more often than the docs, so you won't find everything in the documentation on the laravel website, but you have the source at your hand always.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use where functions with this method. You have to include the where clauses in the array.

```
MyModel::updateOrCreate(array(
    'myField' => 'myValue',
    'myAutoIncrementalField' => '5',
    'myPrimaryKey' => '8'
));
```

Comment: I tried this idea so far but updateOrCreate looks like doesn't care myAutoIncrementalField value. myAutoIncrementalField value comes from a variable, which is an incremental "for loop" value. I'll check it out and let you know for new tests.

Comment: Where did you find the existence of this function? I can't find it anywhere in the documentation or api.

Comment: You can search for Model::updateOrCreate in laravel api.